# convert generic type result to class in lambda expression entity framework in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to retrieve role info as below:

```
var allRoles = (from roles in context.aspnet_Roles 
                select new { roles.RoleId, roles.RoleName }).ToList();
```

I want to store these role data to a specific class type or `LIST<string>` not to object of type `var` like `allRoles`.

Comment: What format would you like the strings in the list to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from these details is that there are a few columns in "context.aspnet_Roles" but, you only want to use RoleId and RoleName. 
Here is what I would do :

```
List<MagicClass> allRoles= new List<MagicClass>();

allRoles= (from roles in context.aspnet_Roles 
          select new MagicClass
          { 
            RoleId = roles.RoleId,
            RoleName = roles.RoleName 
          }).ToList();

internal class MagicClass
{
    private string RoleId {get;set;}
    private string RoleName {get;set;}

};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently selecting a list of anonymous type.  What you seem to want is just the name and as such you should select just the name as a result instead of projecting a new object.

```
var allRoles = (from roles in context.aspnet_Roles 
                select roles.RoleName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the things stored in the list, you change the bit after the `select` keyword.  For example:

```
var allRoles = (from roles in context.aspnet_Roles 
                select "ID=" + roles.RoleId + ";Name=" + roles.RoleName).ToList();
```

The specific expression following the keyword will depend on the string format you want for the list's elements.

By the way, this code does not have any lambda expressions in it.

Comment: Looking for you in the 'generic' chat room

Comment: @GayotFow I await "talk privileges" in that room.

Comment: My bad probably, can you open a room on this site and ping me?

Comment: @GayotFow https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161413/room-for-phoog-and-gayot-fow

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you want to store role name only use this

```
var allRoles = (from roles in context.aspnet_Roles 
            select new { roles.RoleName }).ToList();
```